# MongoDB search to return only specific fields

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using the `$text` feature in MongoDB to search for certain words and want the result to return not the entire document but only the specific fields where this word appears.

I've created the `Text index`:

```
db.Info.ensure_index(
     [("Expenses.description", 'text'),
      ("fullName_normal", 'text')],
     name="searchAll"
 )
```

and do the search as below:

```
text_results = db.Info.find_one({'$and': [{'$text': {'$search': "Hello"}, 'Username': 'John Doe'}]})
```

This returns the whole document only and I only want the specific fields where 'Hello' occurs.

The document is as below:

```
{ 
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54eb8555ccab9321bca808bf"
 },
 "fullName_normal": "username Hello",
 "Expenses":[
        {"description": "Hello",
         "Title": "Widgets",
         "ExpID": "mrsjxKvcSISbFQSSFvZI9g==",
         "Paid": "yes"

        }
    ],
  "Username": "John Doe",
  "Supplier": "no" 
}
```

Comment: On which fields did you add the text index?

Comment: @chridam, just updated my question with fields

Comment: Just project the same fields in your find_one method `db.Info.find_one({'$and': [{'$text': {'$search': "Hello"}, 'Username': 'John Doe'}]}, {"Expenses.description": 1, "fullName_normal": 1}) `

Comment: This also returns `Expenses.description` fields that don't have 'Hello'

Comment: 'Expenses' is an array of dict objects

Comment: Can you show use your document?

Comment: @Michael updated question with document

Comment: This question was also posted to the mongodb-user discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/YMuH5wZLGyM. I've posted a reply there with some possible approaches to consider.

Answer (score 18):

Add a projection document after the searchCriteria document:

```
.find(searchCriteria, projection)
```

You already have your searchCriteria, just add a projection document like the following, where 1 means show the field and 0 means don't show the field:

```
{_id: 0, username: 1, foo: 1}
```

Comment: But this also shows a Expenses description field, which doesn't have the search term: 'Hello' in it

Comment: Try adding 'Expenses.description': 1 to the projection document.

Comment: Tried that and still returns all Expenses.description fields even those without the Hello' string.

Comment: What about... {'Expenses': 0, 'Expenses.description': 1} I'm on my phone or I'd test it out myself. If that doesn't work try turning each field in the array off individually.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'll need to see how to exclude all fields where Expenses.description doesn't have 'Hello' in field.

Comment: For anyone using pymongo, there is a argument projection - http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find